# Why does my rails command keep dissapearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ubuntu-14.04

I installed a rails project in ubuntu 14.04 lts and I was having a problem running the rails command within my project. I thought that I had already installed rails with the rvm install but I reran the command to download it again just to be sure. It worked after that. I was able to run "rails new ..." and "rails server" with no issues inside of my project. I left the room for about an hour and came back and the rails command no longer works. The computer had been left on the whole time. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I am getting the 'rails' can be found in the following packages: ... message

p.s. I already changed the "Run command as a login shell in my gnome terminal".

Comment: can you show the output that you get from running `rvm gemset list` in command line?

Comment: gemsets for ruby-2.1.5 (found in /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5)
    => (default)
    global
   rails4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gemset rails4.1 you created is not set to default. Thats why it cannot recognize the rails command. To fix it you should do something like this:

`rvm use <ruby version>@<gemset name> --default`

In your case you should be doing this:
`rvm use 2.1.5@rails4.1 --default`

Hope it helps!